# JUnit testing internal classes

Tags: java, junit, inner-classes

I have an assignment for university that requires me to have all my code within a single *.java file. The problem I am currently dealing with is that I have a couple support classes written within the application so that at least some of the functionality is separated. The thing is, some of those support classes are quite simple, yet have a lot of functionality.

To make my problem clearer, here is the file structure for my main class.

```
public class Assignment {
  // ...
  protected class UtilClass1 {
    // ...
  }
  protected class UtilClass2 {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

My problem now is that I want to write JUnit test cases for these utility classes, as the various inputs I would have to test manually would be very time consuming, and what I really need is just to test the utility classes.

I have managed to write a simple test that tests a bit of functionality within this single line of code. Like so:

```
  @Before
  public void initAssignment() {
    app = new Assignment();
  }

  @Test
  public void testNumberCreate() {
    assertTrue(app.new Number(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}).toString().equals("12345"));
  }
```

In this particular case, Number is one of the support classes I want to test. One problem I'm having is that I don't know how I would store the inner datatype in a variable, because most tests simply can not be a single line of code.

I am aware that I could solve this problem by making all the inner classes static, but I am wondering if there is another way to achieve this without making them static. Also, I would appreciate any cleaner way to test these classes as this is extremely messy.

Comment: "because most tests simply can not be a single line of code." - Why not?

Comment: I'm not following.  What is the problem?  If your unit test is in the same package as the outer class, you should have no problem instantiating them.  And from your example, it looks like you're good to go.

Comment: Are you looking to do:  `Assignment.Number number = app.new Number(...)` ??

Comment: My tests can't be single lines, because in some cases I have to assert more than one thing, and the inner state has to be changed with multiple methods.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to store the variable, I don't know what data type they are... Silly, I know

That was actually the first thing I tried, but I gives me an error that there is no field that goes by Number in Assignment, which makes sense, so that doesn't really help.

Comment: actually never mind. A stupid mistake on my part, Assignment.Number number = app.new Number(...) did the trick just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public class Foo{

    protected class Bar{}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo.Bar bar = (new Foo()).new Bar();
    }
}
```

No compilation error.  You'll then be able to access any accessible method on `bar`.